# Ms Excel Replace value with the average of the previous and next values

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I'm working with hourly weather data in Excel that has each hour of every day of the year along with the corresponding temperature value that was recorded.

Some of the values weren't recorded, and instead show up as just an "M" on the spreadsheet. For example, A32 = 28, A33 = M, A34 = 30. I want to replace that "M" with a formula to take the average of the previous and next values. I know how to do this manually, but I am having difficulty writing a Macro to find all the M's in the spreadsheet, then auto-replace it as stated above.

My main obstacle is getting excel to use the correct values when replacing the "M".

Here is my code

```
Sub MReplace()
'
' MReplace Macro
'

'
ActiveCell.Select
Cells.Find(What:="M", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(-8, 1).Range("A1").Select
Cells.Find(What:="M", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
ActiveCell.Replace What:="M", Replacement:="[****This is what I am having difficulty with****]", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Find(What:="M", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

I have heard of something that you can put in to the code that can address the selected cell. I think it's cell() but I am not sure. Maybe that is a way to get it to work better?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In general SO is not a code for me site.  If you have tried something, anything, post it in your original post so we may help with specific problems.  You are more likely to get help if you show you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub MReplace()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set cel = ws.Range("A:A").Find("M")

If Not cel Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = cel.Address
    Do
        cel.Value = (cel.Offset(1) + cel.Offset( -1)) / 2
        Set cel = ws.Range("A:A").FindNext(cel)
        hr = False
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            If cel.Address <> firstAddress Then
                hr = True
            End If
        End If
    Loop While hr
End If


End Sub
```

It loops through all the cells containing "M" and replaces it with the average of the one on the right and the one on the left.  It will error on any that are in the first column as there is no column to the left.

Comment: The data I am looking at is importing as one big column of numbers, so would I change that to have the (, 1) and (, -1)  instead say (1 ,) and (-1 ,) in line 13? Thank you so much @scott

Comment: @LucasT Sorry I thought it was a table. see Edit

Comment: @LucasT Did this work for you?  If so please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  It will close out the question as answered.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.   If it did not then what is it doing wrong, so I might fix it.

Comment: Hey Scott, sorry about that, I got caught up with another project and forgot to respond.

For some reason it is not accepting "cel" in line 13. Not sure why since you used it in line 3 and that was accepted just fine.

Comment: @LucasT see edit.  I don't know why it did not work.  But I added some logic to deal with it.